# Position Numbers Above & Below Bars of a Barplot

Tags: r, graphics, legend

I would like to have positive numbers on my barplots displayed above the bars and negative numbers displayed below the bars. Is there anyway to do this in R? Thanks

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
HOLD <- matrix(c(0.711993046435892, 0.732294839190538, 
                 0.393938967564015, -0.456254046041675, 
                 -0.284020839130226, 0.544765413396821, 
                 0.349792656944892, 0.395227638605604, 
                 0.55130390493582, -0.513905184144522, 
                 0.0989034381192891, 0.0908636716369119), ncol=6, nrow=2)

for (i in 1:2) {
  BP <- barplot(HOLD[,i], main=M[[i]], ylab="%", ylim=c(-1, 1), col=SEQUENTIAL)
  text(BP, HOLD[,i], labels=HOLD[,i], pos=3, offset=0.8)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HOLD <- matrix(c(0.711993046435892, 0.732294839190538, 
                 0.393938967564015, -0.456254046041675, 
                 -0.284020839130226, 0.544765413396821, 
                 0.349792656944892, 0.395227638605604, 
                 0.55130390493582, -0.513905184144522, 
                 0.0989034381192891, 0.0908636716369119), ncol=6, nrow=2)

HOLD <- data.frame(HOLD)
HOLD <- stack(HOLD)
HOLD$grp2 <- factor(1:2)
offset <- 0.05
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(data = HOLD, mapping = aes( x = ind, y = values, fill = grp2 ) ) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge' ) +
  geom_text( aes( x     = ind,
                  y     = ifelse( sign( values ) > 0, values + offset, values - offset ),
                  label = round( values, 2 ) ), 
             position = position_dodge( width = 1 ),
             size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using base plot you could just pass a vector to the `pos` argument:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
    BP <- barplot(HOLD[,i], main=M[[i]], ylab="%", ylim=c(-1, 1), col=SEQUENTIAL)
    text(BP, HOLD[,i], labels=HOLD[,i], pos=ifelse(HOLD[i,] >= 0, 3, 1), 
        offset=0.8)
}
```